# Facebook like button says 990k likes on all posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've deleted and reinserted the facebook script and it doesn't change anything. It's the same on every blog post. You can see it here: http://rowboatmedia.com/3818/rowboat-media-brand-new-look/

Answer (score 1):

"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" - This is the URL you put in the data-href parameter, and it is always the same. You need to use your permalink for the specific page in there - meaning, the URL you want to Like.

And don´t forget to add Open Graph Tags, you don´t have any. > http://ogp.me/

Comment: Thank you. That's one of those "I've stared at this code so long I'm missing the obvious."